# Encoding issue for Asset Sync + Rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-sync

I can deploy to heroku successfully, but if I click on my **.css** file I get this

[image]

**Gemfile**

```
gem "asset_sync"
gem "fog"
```

**Asset Syncs**

```
AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'Rackspace'
  config.rackspace_username = ENV['RACKSPACE_USERNAME']
  config.rackspace_api_key = ENV['RACKSPACE_API_KEY']

  # if you need to change rackspace_auth_url (e.g. if you need to use Rackspace London)
  # config.rackspace_auth_url = "lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com"
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']

  # Invalidate a file on a cdn after uploading files
  # config.cdn_distribution_id = "12345"
  # config.invalidate = ['file1.js']

  # Increase upload performance by configuring your region
   config.fog_region = 'ord'
  #
  # Don't delete files from the store
  # config.existing_remote_files = "keep"
  #
  # Automatically replace files with their equivalent gzip compressed version
  # config.gzip_compression = true
  #
  # Use the Rails generated 'manifest.yml' file to produce the list of files to
  # upload instead of searching the assets directory.
  # config.manifest = true
  #
  # Fail silently.  Useful for environments such as Heroku
  # config.fail_silently = true
end
```

**Request headers**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:0ed44d1e0dc7bd6cee17-9854060d787d231b778324765dcb56ab.r59.cf2.rackcdn.com
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 27 Nov 2013 09:31:20 GMT
If-None-Match:546453fdd97eb1e5a500aa49deeffcc7
Referer:http://app.herokuapp.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=258384
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Wed, 27 Nov 2013 09:48:20 GMT
ETag:546453fdd97eb1e5a500aa49deeffcc7
Expires:Sat, 30 Nov 2013 09:34:44 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 27 Nov 2013 09:31:20 GMT
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED.

It was this in one of my css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Comment: How did that solve the problem for you? Can you explain more?